# How to extract string representation of key object

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, equality, key-value

I'm storing items in a strongly typed `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` such that the value also represents the key:

```
public class MyObject
    {

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public SectionId Section { get; private set; }

        public MyObject(SectionId section, string name)
        {
            Section = section;
            Name = name;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != typeof(MyObject)) return false;
            return Equals((MyObject)obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (Name.ToLower().GetHashCode() * 397) ^ Section.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

    }
```

In my presentation tier, I need to iterate through this Dictionary, adding each item to a ListBox control. I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to transform MyObject (which also acts as a key) into a string that the ListBox control can use as a value.  Should I just make an explicit call to MyObject.GetHashCode() like this:

```
MyListBox.Add(new ListItem(myObject.Name, myObject.GetHashCode())
```

Comment: Given a MyObject with Name = "Foo" and Section = (some section ID, lets say this is a numeric value 3), what would you want to see displayed in the Listbox?

Comment: The gethashcode method returns an int. It has no meaning in the presentation layer

Comment: If your value object is also the key, is there a particular reason you must use IDictionary instead of say IEnumerable?

Comment: One of the invariants for MyObject is that there should never be more than one in which Name/Section are duplicated. Rather than enforce this invariant in a hand-rolled IList implementation (checking for uniqueness on Add(), I thought I could use Dictionary semantics and save myself some code.

Comment: Don't know which version of .NET you are on, but can't you use `HashSet<T>`?

Answer (score 1):

I would think of [overriding the toString method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and in here you will basically write code that will generate a meaningful string to be displayed in the ui

Hope I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I just make an explicit call to MyObject.GetHashCode()

No, `GetHashCode()` is:

1. Not guaranteed to give you a unique value, and
2. Going to be very difficult to reverse-engineer to produce a `MyObject` from.

Instead, each of your `MyObject`s should have some kind of unique identifier key. This can be an `enum` value or a number generated by an IDENTITY column in your database, or just a `string` that uniquely identifies each particular `MyObject`, and from which you can retrieve the `MyObject` from whatever collection or database you're using as a repository.

If there can only ever be a single `MyObject` with a given `Name` and `Section`, you could just combine the two: `SectionId + ":" + Name`. That way you can parse those two values out after the fact.

Comment: MyObject is a "hybrid" object (not sure that's the right term). MyObject may represent an entity that has a corresponding database row, or it may represent a non-persistent/derived entity. My attempt to override Equals was a way to circumvent the fact that no database Identifier will exist for all MyObjects.  Is there a better pattern to apply here?

Comment: @Dirk: I assume you're putting it into a ListBox with the intention to allow the user to select a `MyObject`. So on PostBack (I'm assuming Webforms here--an ASP.NET tag may have helped) you will pull out this string value and use it to somehow indicate which `MyObject` the user chose. If you only care about the `Name` or `SectionId` on PostBack, that would make it easier--just use `Name` or `SectionId.ToString()` as the ListItem's value. But if you need more information, you'll need to come up with a way to uniquely identify exactly which `MyObject` to pull that information for.